# Dynamic Table Width

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, width

I have a table cell in which other tables are displayed (with background colors). The inner tables aren't always shown; they can be hidden via a button (change class with jQuery). Now I want the outer cell to always be filled with color. That means if only one table is displayed, its width should be 100%. When two are displayed, each width should be 50%, and so on.
How am I supposed to solve this?

Here's an example:

```
... 
<td>
<table class="show"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
<table class=""><tr><td></td></tr></table>
<table class="show"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</td>
...
```

In this case, the width should be 50%

Comment: you can use JavaScript.

Comment: He can use JavaScript? Nice to know..

Comment: Well, since table cells adjust themselves to their contents, the total width of their contents is 100% by definition. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the width value with Jquery.

```
var count_table = $(".show").length;         // count ".show" elements

$(".show").each(function{                    // iteration on each ".show"
    var width = 100/count_table;             // % value of new width
    $(this).css("width", width+"%");         // CSS modification
});
```

This code is just adapted for one TD element. You need to iterate on each "td" too.

(I hope I answered your problem)

Comment: The solution with $(".show").length seems the best to me. But when I try $(".event.show").length, I get 0 (even when all tables have the class "event show")

Comment: $(".event .show").length Should work with the class "event show". Maybe you forgot a space.

Comment: Had the function placed at the wrong place in my code. Everything works perfectly now, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

To change the width of your elements you can use jquery.

[Here's the page explaining how.](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way: http://jsfiddle.net/ypJDz/1

A bit too complicated for what you need, but a great deal of possibility to expand.

```
function resizeTables() {
    var baby = $("td > table.show"),
        amount = baby.length,
        mother = $("body");

    baby.width(function () {
        var w = mother.width() / amount;
        return w;
    });
}

resizeTables();

$("button").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        ID = $this.index() + 1;

    $("td > table:nth-child(" + ID + ")").toggleClass("show");
    resizeTables();
});
```